# cmdlets on computers exported from AD

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

I've written a Powershell script to automate a process we have been doing manually, but for some reason it does not work when using a .csv of machines exported from AD.  If I query AD for machines with a certain property, output the results to a .csv which are then read into an array and subsequently run any cmdlet on the machines in the array, the cmdlet doesn't fail but always returns a negative result.  For instance, if I run `test-connection -ComputerName $computer` on a computer manually, against a manually created array or an array created from a manually created .csv it returns the proper results.  However, if I run the same command against a .csv created from running the `Get-ADComputer` cmdlet, all machines return false even if they're up and running.  Any ideas on what would cause this?

Comment: You need to be clearer on what you're doing, specifically provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  With what you've provided it would be just guesswork as to what's going on.  For example, what does the CSV look like and how do you `run the same command against a .csv`?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're running? `Get-ADComputer` doesn't really tell you nothing about the computer itself as it's querying AD, and not the system itself. Just from reading this, if the AD cmdlets aren't responding properly, I would point it to a different DC using the `-Server` parameter; perhaps the ones those computers are authenticating to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses.  I was actually able to get assistance elsewhere and get it figured out.  Due to hostname length variations, Get-ADComputer was adding trailing spaces so they were all the same length.  This wasn't visible in .csv .  After removing the trailing spaces from each hostname it worked normally.